# Declare keys in a library to be used in a application

Tags: ios, objective-c, static-libraries

I am creating a static library.

In this, I would like to declare keys similar to Apple's declaration of `UITextAttributeFont`.

```
UIKIT_EXTERN NSString *const UITextAttributeFont NS_DEPRECATED_IOS(5_0, 7_0, "Use NSFontAttributeName");

// Key to the text color in the text attributes dictionary. A UIColor instance is expected.
UIKIT_EXTERN NSString *const UITextAttributeTextColor NS_DEPRECATED_IOS(5_0, 7_0, "Use NSForegroundColorAttributeName");

// Key to the text shadow color in the text attributes dictionary.  A UIColor instance is expected.
UIKIT_EXTERN NSString *const UITextAttributeTextShadowColor NS_DEPRECATED_IOS(5_0, 7_0, "Use     NSShadowAttributeName with an NSShadow instance as the value");

// Key to the offset used for the text shadow in the text attributes dictionary. An NSValue instance wrapping a UIOffset struct is expected.

UIKIT_EXTERN NSString *const UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset NS_DEPRECATED_IOS(5_0, 7_0, "Use NSShadowAttributeName with an NSShadow instance as the value");
```

In one of my methods, I am expecting a `NSDictionary` from the end developer.

This `dictionary` should contain values for the key that I have described.

I tried doing it using, but in the application it is throwing an error, which says that the constant has not been declared.

My Declaration:

```
/*In header file */

extern NSString *const event1;
extern NSString *const event2;
```

I am assigning values to these constants inside .m of the file.

```
NSString *const event1 = @"My_Event";
NSString *const event2 = @"My_Second_Event";
```

How can I allow the user to use the keys in the dictionary as specified my constant values?

Comment: Constants needs to be assigned while declaring. Try moving declaration and definition to .h ?

Comment: Also, Can you please post the code how you are using this constants?

Comment: Is moving the constant definition the only way where it will be possible.
How does UIKit define its constants then?

Comment: Tried using your steps, It is compiling without any problem and its able to resolve the constant string. I hope you have added the header (.h) and library file (.a) to the project. Also you have imported the .h file.